# Avoid compiling the LESS file in CSS format

Tags: css, sass, less

I have some `.less` files in a folder of my project.
I use PHPStorm, and it can automatically compile the `.less` files in CSS format.

Because I have to import some of these `.less` files into the main `less` file, I don't want them to be compiled as a single CSS file; instead, I just want the `main.less` file that I imported the other `.less` files into it, to compile in a CSS file so I can add it to a page.

For instance in SCSS, for this purpose we add an underscore at the beginning of the file name; then that SCSS file won't compile again.

I tried to use this way in LESS, too but it didn't work.

Comment: I can't say for sure, but I would assume LESS operates the same as SASS in that respect. Why not try it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I tried adding underscore at the beginning of LESS files like what we do in SASS but my IDE again compiled it to CSS files but I didn't want it to compile because I wanted to import that file in another LESS file so I didn't need to compile it.